# Why LinkExtractor does not catch the links that was generated after AJAX requests?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm crawling a page that generates data with infinite scrolling.
I'm using CrawlSpider, and the `rules` are defined like this:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ('//*some/xpaths')), callback = 'parse_first_itmes', follow = True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ('//*some/other/xpaths')), callback = 'parse_second_itmes'),
)
```

In the `parse_item` function, I have a `Request` makes the `AJAX` requests:

```
def parse_first_items(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item = AmazonCnCustomerItem(), response = response)

    l.add_xpath('field1', '//p[@class="field1")]/text()')
    l.add_xpath('field2', '//p[@class="field2")]/text()')

    r_url = l.get_xpath('//*/url/xpath/@href')

    r = Request(url = req_url,
                    headers = {"Referer": "the/same/page/url",
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
                    callback = self.parse_first_items)

    return r, l.load_item()
```

I get the desired data just fine, but the `LinkExtractor` in the `Second Rule` does not catch the `urls` from the data generated by the `Request` inside the the `parse_first_itmes` function.

How can I make the `LinkExtractor` in the `Second Rule` extract those links and use them to parse the `parse_second_itmes` function?

Comment: Have you checked if the requests are actually sent? Or if they receive a response from the server?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's just that `LinkExtractor` doesn't have access to the data that was loaded by the `Request` inside the function. The requests are actually sent and they receive response, that's how I get _**new data**_, e.g.:(`field1` and `field2`) that were not there before the `Request`. It's just that LinkExtractor doesn't extract links from the the data generated by the `Request` inside the function.