# Can I add links manually to LinkExtractor?

Tags: python, scrapy

It looks like that LinkExtractor can't extract links from data that was loaded/generated by an ajax request inside a function ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38777236/587990))!

So, is there a way to add extract links in the function and then add them manually to LinkExtractor, or force LinkExtractor to grab them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly here but it seems you are confusing `LinkExtractor` with `CrawlSpider.rules`. LinkExtractor is just an object which extracts links from response, where rules attribute describes crawling rules for `CrawlSpider`.

If you want to use CrawlSpider while manually extracting some links yourself, you can do that simply by:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    le = LinkExtractor()
    rules = [Rule(le, callback='parse_page')...]

    def parse_page(self, response):
        items = #parse items
        for item in items:
            yield item
        ajax_url = #find ajax url for next page or something
        if ajax_url:
            yield Request(ajax_url, self.parse_ajax)

    def parse_ajax(self, response):
        links = self.le.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            yield Request(link.url, self.parse_page)
```

Comment: Doesn't the documentation say that `parse` function can not be used with `CrawlSpider`? And I mean the `LinkExtractor` that is used in the `CrawlSpider.rules`.

Comment: right, `parse` is reserved name by CrawlSpider. I initially wrote the example using scrapy.Spider and just forgot to change it. See my edit now. Regarding linkextractor, what's wrong here? You create a link extractor and add it to your rules and use it later to extract some links in parse_ajax() - it's the same link extractor.

Comment: No no, please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38777236/587990) to understand what my problem is. I'll giv your code a shot.

Comment: Exactly! So how can I got those links?

Comment: @XO39 You need to deal with them manually. That's exactly what my answer shows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120227/discussion-between-xo39-and-granitosaurus).

Comment: Your answer got me started, and I got working the way I want. :)